# UICollectionView received memory warning while scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview

I am developing an App with an `UICollectionView` in one `ViewController`.

This `CollectionView` it's a gallery with 3 images in each row.

[image: CollectionView]

I get the images from the server in groups of 30 pictures, first url and code, and when the cell is going to be displayed in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` I use `SDWebImage Library` to download those pictures asynchronously. Every 30 pictures I call again the web service and I get 30 pictures more sending the request with limit and offset. This could happen 100 times, there are profiles with 3000 pictures.

Well, my problem comes one I launch the app in my iPhone 4, after some fast scrolling I start getting `Received Memory Warnings` and after some warnings the app crashes.  When I make the same test in the Simulator, nothing bad happens.

Each time I download 30 pictures I add the result array to the `NSMutableArray *data property` which handles the `CollectionView` data and **`reload`** the `collectionView`. I have tried to use Instruments with allocations, but it is very difficult for me to understand what is happening.

This is the code I use to create the cells

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(LZProfileImagesCollectionView *)aCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(aCollectionView == self.imagesCollectionView){
        if([self.data count] - 12 == indexPath.row){
            self.photoOffset += 30;
            [self loadUserData];
        }

        LZProfileCollectionViewCell * cell = (LZProfileCollectionViewCell *)[imagesCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:ImageCollectionCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        Image *image =(self.data)[indexPath.row];
        [cell configureCellWithImage:image];

        return cell;
    }
    return  nil;
}
```

And in the `LZProfileCollectionViewCell` cell I have this one:

```
-(void)configureCellWithImage:(Image *)image
{
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

    // Imagen
    NSString *imageUrl  = [kBaseURL stringByAppendingString:image.imageStringUrl];
    [self.pictureImg setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kDefaultLoadingImage]];
    [self.pictureImg setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

}
```

I have taken `setImageWithURL` from [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

After 3 minutes I get this snapshot in the Instruments(Statistics)

[image: Statistics]

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you are using a third-party library it is up to you to ensure that you have configured it for appropriate caching.  You are also responsible for clearing that cache when you need to free memory. What does the Allocations instrument say about where memory is being used?

Comment: I use `AFNetworking` for usual requests and `SDWebImage` for image asynchronous download. What do you want to see in Instruments allocations? Call trees, allocation list?

Comment: Start with `Statistics`->`Object Summary` and look at the top `Live Bytes` objects.  Or post a screen shot. Take some heap shots as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are caching every image in an array, so once you cache so many images you are eventually going to run out of memory.  It doesn't happen on the simulator because the simulator has as much memory as the computer running it, so it is unlikely to ever run out of memory, a real device however will run out very fast.  I'd handle the memory error yourself and empty the array, to free up new space for new images.  Or better yet create your own caching mechanism to hold and clear images that haven't been in view for a while, either way you have to have some way to dump images after you hit a certain threshold.

Comment: But.. My array only save URL and code of the picture, not the picture itself

Comment: This is not the right answer, the problem is that you never release the image which is loaded in each cell

Answer (score 0):

In the method `– didReceiveMemoryWarning` you should free some memory of the array where you are stored the images. Maybe the first images that you are not displaying stored it a second array like an auxiliar array.

Comment: But, if I scroll up again, I should replace the items in the array again, should not I ?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because a lot of `UIImage` objects end up in memory. You could instead cache this on disk. `AFNetworking` has a nice [`UIImageView` category](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit+AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h) that does all of this automatically.

If you're not saving the Images in your dataSource array, then they're probably being retained somewhere else, which is a bug.

Also, make sure you're `dequeuing` cells and not creating new ones.

Comment: I use `setImageWithURL`  SDWebImage Library method. Is it similar?

Comment: Their ultimate effect might be similar, but I'm not sure if SDWebImage does disk caching or not.

Comment: SDWebImage **An asynchronous memory + disk image caching with automatic cache expiration handling** https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: I actually don't do that. I just keep the image in cache, but not disk cache. I am going to try it

Comment: How can I cache my Images on disk with AFNetworking? I don't think AFNetworking does this automatically. I have tried with `[self.pictureImg setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kDefaultLoadingImage]];` of that category and the same happens. I can't do it with SDWebImage either.. I have realised that the problem is not when I make scroll, it is when  the cell get the images into the cache as you say.

Comment: @croigsalvador have you any solution for this because we are also facing same kind of issue lot of images with SDWebImageCache and collectionView leads to crash.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced similar situation so I'm replying on this issue though the reason seems a little different from yours.

I have a horizontal UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell. When I scroll UICollectionView right and left rapidly, the entire UI(even a home button) stops and after a while the app crashes with the message "**Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue**" on the console even without didReceiveMemoryWarning call.

I tested it with a UICollectionViewCell without any UI components but no changes. XCode Profile tool says it's actually keep allocating memory during the UI's stopped until it crashes even without any UI components in it.

The only suspicious point was that I was setting the width of a UICollectionViewCell's subview(custom UIView pinned to all superview edges) with **AppDelegate.window.size.width * 0.35** to determine UICollectionViewCell's width and it was a float value like 130.25

When I hardcode this value to 130, all the crashes are gone. I think something was happening under the hood with this vague value of 130.25 and it's determining the width as 130 or 130.25 occasionally.

So I'm using **CGFloat(Int(AppDelegate.window.size.width * 0.35))** now and everything's fine.